# Datamapper: How to count total score from has_many objects

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper, has-many

I just started learning some database basics. I am using **Ruby** and the **datamapper gem**

I have two simple objects:

```
class Quote
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :saying, String, :required => true
  property :score, Integer, :default => 5
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :quotes
end
```

No I would like to get the **total score** of a user. The total score is the sum of the scores of all associated quotes of a user.

I tried something like

```
@totalscore = @user.quotes.inject(0) {|count, q| count + q.score}
```

but I guess this can't be the way I am supposed to use a database, right?

Any help is appreciated!

Best,

Tobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not running the code, but by looking at the [docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html), I think something like this should work:

```
@totalscore = @user.quotes.sum :score
```